# Google Docs Viewer with Amazon S3 PDF Link Error

Tags: google-docs

I am attempting to use GoogleDocs Viewer to embed a PDF on my webpage.

This is the link that was generated but I keep getting an error:

```
Sorry, we are unable to retrieve the document for viewing or you don't have permission to view the document.  Please try again later.
```

Can google not handle S3 docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Docs Viewer has a limit of 2 Mb for PDF files.

If your document is larger than that you will get this error.